# Creating a button to switch between xib files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, keyboard, ios8, custom-keyboard

Currently my custom keyboard has only one layout: the Qwerty keyboard is only letters. I want to create a button that will switch to the numbers and symbol part of every keyboard. Because I am new to programming I figured I should make two different xib files: one with letters and the other with numbers and symbols. In order to switch between the two xib files (Keyboard.xib and AltKeyboard.xib) I tried to create a button in the AltKeyboard.xib that would go to the Keyboard.xib and this is my code:

```
#pragma mark AltKeyboard
-(void)addGesturesToAltKeyboard{
[self.altKeyboard.altKey addTarget:self action:@selector(initWithNibName:"Keyboard"              bundle: nil) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

However, this does not work, so I was wondering if I could get some advice in what I could do now.

Comment: the keyboard type is a property of the textField. `myField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;`